# Run a wp meta query arg for each item in an array

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this array with a list of values, and I'm trying to check it against a wp-post and find the cheapest.

So far I have this

```
  $sources = array("source 1", "source 2", "source 3", "source 4");

  foreach($sources as $source) {
  $args .= array(
    'post_type' => 'streaming-service-db',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'guidebox_source',
            'value' => $source,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);  
}               
$query = new WP_Query($args);               
if($query->have_posts()) : 
    while($query->have_posts()) : 
        $source_id = get_the_ID();  
        $price = get_field( 'cost' , $source_id);           
        if ( get_field( 'cost' , $source_id) ==  min($price) ){
            echo get_title($source_id)." is the cheapest at". get_field( 'cost' , $source_id);
        } 
         break; 
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

So I know its completely wrong and wouldn't work as is, but it should give a better idea of what im trying to do.

Start with an array $sources

Find the $source_id by looking up the meta key value "guidebox_source"

Get their prices using get_field( 'cost' , $source_id)

And compare the prices to find the lowest.

Comment: How many of these `streaming-service-db` do you have?  10's, 100's, millions?

Comment: up to 300 sources

Comment: im thinking of using something like rsort($prices); $min_price = $prices[0];

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to use it in this case. How do i sort the prices, and then echo out the rest of the info apart from the price, like titles

Comment: Why don't you update your question to where you are now?